# Is it possible to place an OU under a non-OU at Active Directory

Tags: go, active-directory, synchronization

I want to search all OU in the AD with LDAP for sync,I have encountered an issue.
example:

```
-[OU] officeA
--[OU] officeA2
--[OU] officeA3

-[OU] officeB
--[G] ZXC
---[OU] officeB3
```

[G] ZXC just random example, I would like to know under what circumstances an OU would exist under a non-OU.

I have attempted to add an OU under both User and Groups in Active Directory Users and Computers, but all attempts have failed.

--- 2023/08/29
So OU can only under an OU,maybe OU can be change to not [OU] by policies assigned?
(I searched with GOLANG's func (l *Conn) SearchWithPaging)

Answer (score 0):

An OU can be created under a "Container". The main difference between an Organizational Unit and a Container is that an OU can have policies assigned to it.

User and Group objects cannot have child objects, so you cannot put an OU "inside" them. A group object has members (objects listed in its `member` attribute), not child objects.